# A cursor with the name ... already exists - SQL Server 2008

Tags: java, sql, sql-server, t-sql, database-cursor

I have a trigger that is used to perform some auditing tasks when changes are made to a table. Within this trigger there is a WHILE loop, and in the loop there is a cursor that is declared, used, closed and then deallocated before the next iteration of the loop.

When I call a stored procedure that changes the table and in turn causes the trigger to run, and I do this from within the Management Studio, all works as expected.

However, when this stored procedure is called from within my Java web application, I get an error: "A cursor with the name ...  already exists".

Is there a reason why this stored procedure would work when I execute it manually, and not work when run from the web application?

Comment: A trigger that has a cursor and a while loop is a trigger that needs to be refactored.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

It sounds like you might be using GLOBAL cursors, which could cause problems like this.

If you must use cursors:

If you can, use LOCAL cursors in all your code. 
e.g. declare cursor using the "LOCAL" keyword, like this:

```
DECLARE yourcursor CURSOR LOCAL ...
```

Comment: This fixed my issue with cursors in a multithreaded application. Can also be set to default to local through the database options:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188124(v=sql.105).aspx

Answer (score 7):

You can also try this

```
IF CURSOR_STATUS('global', 'Cursorname') >= -1
BEGIN
    CLOSE Cursorname
    DEALLOCATE Cursorname
END
```

Comment: This was exactly my problem. I had the cursor break in the middle of a transaction and it never deallocated it. This solved it. Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

Sounds a little like it is being called by multiple threads and therefore already exists when the second thread tries to use the name. You might try naming your cursor dynamically with a GUID in the name etc.  I would not recommend this approach.

I suggest you remove the cursor from your trigger code if at all possible in favour of a set based approach. Overhead of using a cursor within the trigger must be pretty high.