# Getting A cursor with the name 'assay_cursor' already exists

Tags: sql-server-2008

```
 DECLARE @CName varchar(20)

 DECLARE assay_cursor CURSOR  
 FOR
    SELECT 
        [LP ].[LP Code]
    FROM [LP ] 
    INNER JOIN [Assay Info] ON [LP ].[LP Code] = [Assay Info].[LP Code] 
    WHERE 
        ((([LP ].Report) = 1))
    GROUP BY 
        [LP ].[LP Code], [Assay Info].[Assay Date], [LP ].ZDescription

 OPEN assay_cursor
 FETCH NEXT FROM assay_cursor INTO @CName

 WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
 BEGIN 
    PRINT @CName 
    FETCH NEXT FROM assay_cursor
 END

 CLOSE assay_cursor
 DEALLOCATE assay_cursor
```

The logic inside loop has been removed. I want to iterate through the codes and then dump the data in a new temp table.

Comment: depending on the logic in your loop if you are just dumping data then you likely do not need a cursor.

Comment: What if you use a different cursor name one time? Also, could be this: [global cursor](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6735719/a-cursor-with-the-name-already-exists-sql-server-2008)